# How to typecast enum values as an array in typescript's interface/types?

Tags: typescript, enums, interface, typescript-types

I want to typecast a prop of an interface/types property as an array of any element matching with enum values.

```
enum X = {
"one" = 1,
"two" = 2,
"three" = 3,
// .... and so on
}

interface Y {
 prop: X[] // this array should always contains values from enum only, not necessarily all
}
```

(a) prop: ["one", "two"] --- valid

(b) prop: ["one"] --- valid

(c) prop: ["one", "XYZ"] --- invalid, if "XYZ" is not part of enum

I am not sure how should I typecast my prop so that it should match the list of enum values only.

Any help would be appreciated !!!

Thanks

Comment: Your enum definition is not valid. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAGlDeAoKBDKBeKByAjFgNMgEYbYBMWiAvoogJYgAuwATgGYoDGwUAmgsgAOLAPaCAXLADaAXWq1OIkAGdGUNiJGT+meFGFjJUmADoUMqFSA

Comment: An enum member cannot have a numeric name.ts(2452)

Comment: sorry it was my bad, I have corrected it.

Comment: So you're trying to extract enum keys as a type?

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating `interface` like below -

```
var myList = Object.keys(X) as Array<keyof typeof X>;

interface Y {
  prop: typeof myList;
}
```

Then blow are the test:

```
const test0: Y = { prop: ['one', 'two', 'three'] }; // Valid
const test1: Y = { prop: ['one', 'two'] }; // Valid
const test2: Y = { prop: ['one'] }; //Valid
const test3: Y = { prop: ['one', 'XYZ'] }; //Error
const test4: Y = { prop: ['Two', 'zz'] }; //Error
```